# PDF from HTML with only alphabetic (Latin) using itextpdf

Tags: java, android, unicode, itext

I believe that the answer to my question is very easy for those who have had experience with this, and I thank you in advance.

Namely, I managed to export a PDF file from TextView `bodyText` and `titleText`, but my problem is that only alphabetic (Latin) letters can be seen in that PDF file, I can't see an example in Arabic, Cyrillic, Indian or Hebrew, etc. Can anyone help me, thanks !!!!!!!!

In Gradle I use: `implementation 'com.itextpdf.tool:xmlworker:5.5.3'`

```
OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("MyPath"));
                            
Document document = new Document (PageSize.A4);

PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
                            
document.open();
                            
Paragraph title = new Paragraph();
title.add(titleText.getText().toString());
title.setSpacingAfter(12.0f);
title.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
document.add(title);
document.add(new Paragraph("\n"));
HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(Html.toHtml((Spanned) bodyText.getText())));
    
document.close();
file.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the font that you decided to use when exporting. **Some fonts do not support non-Latin characters.**

As a result you can use fonts like:

- CODE2000
- Arial Unicode MS

To use it with itextpdf I refrenced this: [Click here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/itext/itext_setting_font.htm)

```
font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.CODE2000)
text1.setFont(font);
```

Comment: itextpdf cannot resolve symbol PdfFont and PdfFontFactory, where is a problem?